# Removing NULL from Hive table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table where in some columns have 'NULL' value, my downstream program does not accept NULL values, I could write a switch case statement to replace nulls with a blank ' ' but I am looking for a more efficient way to do like altering the table properties to show blank instead of null.

Comment: You can have Hive represent nulls as an empty string.  How it works depends on how your table is defined.

Comment: How can i do that ?
I tried alter table tab_name set tblproperties('serialization.null.format'=FALSE)

Comment: `TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format'='')` That's an empty string at the end there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this query to interpret 'NULL' in underlying data as an empty string.

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(column1,'NULL','') FROM MyTable;
```

**Illustration:**

```
-- This is the Hive table

> desc hive_tbl;

col_name                data_type
h1                      string
h2                      string
h3                      string
h4                      string

-- This is the query that interprets h2 having 'NULL' as another character. 
-- In this case, 'X' is used instead of '' so that it prints in the display.

> SELECT h1, h2, h3, h4, TRANSLATE(h2,'NULL','X') h2_updated FROM hive_tbl;

h1  h2      h3  h4                                                h2_updated
1   foo     100 entry-foo                                         foo
2   NULL    200 The data is absent for second column              NULL
3   NULL    300 The value in second column is the string NULL     X
```